# Meteor get Files via GridFS of a Remote Collection

Tags: mongodb, file, meteor, gridfs

I am connecting to some remote collections via the following pattern:

```js
let remoteDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:7071/meteor");

export const RemoteCollection = new Mongo.Collection("remoteCollection", {_driver:remoteDB});
```

Which is working fine for normal collections.

However, there is a [FilesCollection (via ostrio:files)](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) that also exists in this remote DB.

The FileCollection constructor does not let me pass the _driver options, so I am asking if someone has managed to load the remote files via gridfs, before opening a ticket on the project.

Comment: I'd open a ticket, or make a pull request. Dr-dimitru is very responsive to questions and feature requests, and this seems like it shouldn't be too complicated. Just exposing an option to pass through to the underlying Collection

Comment: I am just not sure if this has not obviously been already integrated somehow. I checked the code but am I am as always just confused by coffeescript.

Comment: Though I just looked and you can pass a Collection into the constructor. So you could pass RemoteCollection to FilesCollection and maybe access the files through that?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I will check that out first.

Comment: Yeah lines [126-130 of `server.js`](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/server.js#L126-L130) and [lines 73-77 of `client.js`](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/client.js#L73-L77) show where the `Collection` is created. No options being passed in. So your best bet is to pass in your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of Meteor-Files, the `Mongo.Collection` is added in [lines 126-130 of `server.js`](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/server.js#L126-L130) and [lines 73-77 of `client.js`](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/client.js#L73-L77) without any options being passed in.

What you can do is pass your own `RemoteCollection` into the `FilesCollection` constructor and the collection will use your collection and it's remote.

```
let remoteDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:7071/meteor");

export const RemoteCollection = new Mongo.Collection("remoteCollection", {_driver:remoteDB});

export const RemoteFilesCollection = new FilesCollection({
  collectionName: "remoteCollection",
  collection: RemoteCollection
});
```

You'll also need to add all the extra code for GridFS integration to Meteor-Files: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/GridFS-Integration